# Output comes in dictionary sorted order in python

Tags: python, csv, file-io, export-to-csv

I have a collection of csv files with names like `2.csv` , `3.csv` ...., `999.csv`. Each file has 91 rows in it. I want to have a set of new files collecting a particular row from all the files. Eg. `row1.csv` should have first row of all the 998 files and similarly row35.csv should have 35th row of all the 998 files. Therefore I should have in total 91 files (one for each row) with each file having 998 rows (one for each original file) after my script completes the run.

I use the following code for the task

```
import glob
import os
for i in range(2,92):
  outfile = open("row_%i.csv" %i,'w')
  for filename in glob.glob('DataSet-MediaEval/devFeatures/*.csv'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
      lineno = 0 
      for line in infile:
        lineno += 1
        if lineno == i:
          outfile.write(line)
  outfile.close()
```

Now in any of the outfile `row_i.csv` my data is arranged in dictionary sorted order. Example :

First row in `row_50.csv` file is the 50th row of `10.csv`.

In other words in any `row_i.csv` the rows comes from `10.csv`, `100.csv`, 101.csv and so on.

I wanted to know why is that happening and is there a way in which I can ensure that my r`ow_i.csv` is ordered in the way the files are ordered i.e. `2.csv`, `3.csv` and so on.

Thanks for the time spent reading this.

Comment: Probably `glob` is sorting the file names, which are strings. Just cache the filenames in a list and custom-sort that list. Hm, just `glob`ed some random files and they came out in random order. Anyway, you'll have to sort the filenames.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am looping over all the files once for each row number I wish to add. See the out most for loop. The rows are numbered from 2 -- 92

Comment: @tobias_k I do not store all the files at once. I open the file extracts the row  and close it down. So you mean I should somehow also store the file name in the outfile and then sort each outfile individually with respect to the filename.

Comment: Sounds like you mean in "directory", not "dictionary", order. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this works out or if there are more problems, but it seems like `glob` either returns the filenames in sorted order (sorted as strings), or in random order. In both cases, you will have to extract the number from the filenames and sort by that number.

Try something like this:

```
p = re.compile(r"/(\d+)\.csv")
filenames = glob.glob(...)
for filename in sorted(filenames, key=lambda s: int(re.search(p, s).group(1))):
    ...
```

Also, it seems like you are opening, looping and closing all those 999 files for all of the 92 outfiles again and again! It might be better to open all of the 92 outfiles at once and store them in a dictionary, mapping line numbers to files. This way, you have to loop the 999 files just once.

Something like this (totally not tested):

```
outfiles = {i: open("row_%i.csv" %i, 'w') for i in range(2,92)}
p = re.compile(r"/(\d+)\.csv")
filenames =  glob.glob('DataSet-MediaEval/devFeatures/*.csv'):
for filename in sorted(filenames, key=lambda s: int(re.search(p, s).group(1))):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(infile):
            outfiles[lineno].write(line)
for outfile in outfiles.values():
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: Writing all the files at once would definitely be a more efficient and likely much faster approach — although you might want to use a `try/finally` to ensure they're all always closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the filename list before start iteration on it. This can help you:

```
import re
import glob

filename_list = glob.glob('DataSet-MediaEval/devFeatures/*.csv')

def splitByNumbers(x):
    r = re.compile('(\d+)')
    l = r.split(x)
    return [int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in l]

filenames = sorted(filename_list, key = splitByNumbers)
```

then you can use instead of

```
for filename in glob.glob('DataSet-MediaEval/devFeatures/*.csv'):
```

this

```
for filename in filenames:
```

Comment: This will sort the filenames lexicographically, not numerically, so for example the resulting order would still be `10.csv`, `100.csv`, `101.csv`, `2.csv`, etc.

Comment: not true. Tested on python2.7. The function splitByNumbers is used exactly for sorting numerically. Try it and you will see by yourself.

Comment: Well, it seems to work indeed, but it might be a bit overhead to sort by all the segments instead of by just the number. Then again, this approach is probably more general, i.e. it also works if the rest besides the number is not the same for each file. Thumbs up. Might put the `re.compile` outside of the function, though.

Comment: The sorting problem is that the function converts each file name into a list of single digit numbers and uses them as the sort key. The result is not the same as sorting them numerically. i.e. `sorted([[1], [2], [1,0,0]])` results in this order: `[[1], [1, 0, 0], [2]]`.

Comment: @martineau Maybe this depends on the Python version. With Python 2.7 and 3.4, it splits `"foo34bar12"` into `['foo', '34', 'bar', '12', '']`, which will sort fine.

Comment: @tobias_k: I get the same results from `sorted([[1], [2], [1,0,0]])` in Python 3.4.3. It has to do with how Python sorts lists (which hasn't changed between 2.x and 3.x).

Comment: @martineau What I meant: for me, the `splitByNumbers` function does not split up numbers, i.e. for an input string like `"foo23"` I get `["foo", 23]`, and not `[2, 3]`, so sorting works okay.